# ¿Como puedo hacer que me imprima datos de tipo String?

Tags: java, string, pilas, imprimir

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Borrar {
static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Stack<String> pila1 = new Stack <String>();
    Stack<String> pila2 = new Stack <String>();
    
    int datoB, dato;
    
    pila1.push(Integer.toString(8));
    pila1.push(Integer.toString(7));
    pila1.push(Integer.toString(6));
    pila1.push(Integer.toString(5));
    
    System.out.println("Datos Borrables de la pila:");
    System.out.println("8");
    System.out.println("7");
    System.out.println("6");
    System.out.println("5");
    System.out.println("*****************************");
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese dato a Borrar");
    datoB= entrada.nextInt();
    
    while(!pila1.empty()) {
        dato=Integer.parseInt(pila1.pop());
        if(dato!=datoB)
            pila2.push(Integer.toString(dato));
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(!pila2.empty())
        pila1.push(pila2.pop());
    System.out.println("**Dato Borrado**");
    System.out.println(pila1);

}
```

Me gustaría saber como cambiar para que me pueda imprimir la pila solo valores de tipo String como en vez de los números Nombres:(

Comment: No se entiende tu duda, porfavor se mas claro.

Comment: o disculpa me cambiaron lo que habia puesto
mi problema esque quiero imprimir nombres en la pila pero al ponerlos me marca error intente cambiando las variables"datoB" y "dato" y no funciono

Comment: Cual error te sale.